# PasteSpecial method of Range class failed in for loop

Tags: excel, vba

Writing macros to copy cells in a different workbook in a specific format.Getting error at different lines everytime I run the code

I tried with unhide cells, selection

```
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & i).Value) = False Then
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & i).Font.Bold = True Then
            'Range("A" & i).Copy Range("B" & i)
            Set BoldTitle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & i)
            x = i
        Else
            ws.Range("A" & i).Value = "Winter I"

            BoldTitle.Copy
            ws.Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & i).Copy
            ws.Range("C" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("B" & i).Copy
            ws.Range("D" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("C" & i).Copy
            ws.Range("E" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & i).Copy
            ws.Range("F" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Else
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The range `BoldTitle` is only set if Summary!A1 is bold. In that case the rest of the code doesn't run. But if the range was never set it can't be copied in subsequent loops. BTW, consider copying the 6 cells all in one operation.

Comment: Please mention full code such as declaration of variables i.e. Dim part. How you have determined lastrow. Generally problem encountered by you comes when workbook and worksheet references are not set properly.